# Can I get Doxygen to use untagged comments, on function prototypes?

Tags: doxygen

The company I'm working for does not use Doxygen, and in their coding standard explicitly prohibits "parseable comment styles such as javadoc, etc".

However, I've still found it very useful to run Doxygen myself just so I can see the class structure, and get nice per-class documentation of all the methods the a class has, including inherited ones.

The company does document the classes in the header files, with simple comments above each method declaration. It would be very useful if I could configure Doxygen to treat these comments as the function descriptions, even though they don't start with any Doxygen markers.

So: is it possible to get Doxygen to treat comments on the line above declarations as if they are the description for that item even when the comment is not marked with Doxygen's "parse this comment" markers?

The next best thing is to click on the `#include <foo.h>` links at the top of the class file to jump to the file itself, which I have been using. That doesn't help for seeing all of a derived class's methods in one place, though.

Comment: Strange that such things are forbidden, what could be the rationale behind this or is the company afraid that would make it easy to understand the code or do they want to hide something... Best would be to convince the responsible people about the benefits of the usage of e.g. doxygen.

Comment: Do the comments above the methods have only "normal" comments i.e. with `/*` or `//` or do they start with `/**` or `///` etc. (or are these forbidden as well)? Probably bests would be that you write a small filter (see e.g. `INPUT_FILTER`) in which you convert (all?) `/*` / `//` comments into `/**` / `///` so the comment blocks are parsed by doygen. The result is not as nice as with "full" doxygen comments but probably best you can do  and after obtaining some results convince the responsible people to use doxygen.

Comment: I don't know what the rationale is yet. It's only my second week there, so it'll take a while before I'm in a position to convince people to switch. The INPUT_FILTER idea looks promising, though.

Comment: Perfect! I just used `sed`. Do you want to add that as an actual answer, so I can accept it?

Comment: Indeed a bit hard to already convince people but as you have a small mockup with `sed` you have something to show. Best probably is first direct colleagues  (talking at them at the coffee machine). A good company should always have a good listening ear for innovations / improvements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the comments above the methods have only "normal" comments i.e. with `/*` or `//` the best thing to do would be that you write a small filter (see e.g. `INPUT_FILTER` with `sed` or `awk` or ... ) in which you convert (all?) `/*` / `//` comments into `/**` / `///` so the comment blocks are parsed by doxygen. The result is not as nice as with "full" doxygen comments.

It is just a workaround and can lead to unexpected results when the `INPUT_FILTER` does not exclude e.g. `//` inside strings from consideration.

Comment: I ended up going with `FILTER_PATTERNS`, set to only do header files. So far so good.